# Derived Hom and tensor of chain complexes homologically concentrated in degree zero

Tags: commutative-algebra, derived-functors, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and let $X,Y\in \mathcal D_0(R)$ (i.e. $X,Y$ are represented by chain complexes with only non-zero homology at the $0$-th spot).

Then, is it true that

$$\text{H}_n \mathbf R\text{Hom}_R(X,Y) =\text{H}_{-n} \left(X \otimes_R^{\mathbf L}Y\right)=0,\forall n>0\ ?$$

I think this is true because in $\mathcal D(R)$ we have the isomorphisms $X\cong \text H_0(X)$ and $Y\cong \text H_0(Y)$, hence essentially $X,Y\in \text{Mod} (R)$.
Am I correct?

Comment: If you believe this statement is true for $\operatorname{Mod}(R)$, then a quick way to see it's validity is to note that the functor $[0]:\operatorname{Mod}(R)\to D(R)$ sending module $M$ to a complex $M[0]$ concentrated in degree $0$ has essential image equivalent to the subcategory of $D(R)$ of complexes with cohomology concentrated in degree $0$.

Comment: A quick sanity check to note that this has "no chance" of being always the case is the the left hand side is contravariant in $X$, while the right hand side is covariant. Of course, as the answers show, it is far from being always the case, in fact it is almost always not the case; but this sanity check is a good way of seeing that it "shouldn't"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, as you've notice in $\mathcal D(R)$ you have $X\simeq H_0(X)$ and $Y\simeq H_0(Y)$, so you can assume that $X$ and $Y$ are just $R$-modules considered as complexes concentrated in degree $0$.

Now, according to the definition of $X\otimes_R^\mathbf{L}Y$ I am going off of, i.e. [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06XY), you can calculate $X\otimes_R^\mathbf{L}Y$ by taking a "K-flat resolution" $ K_\bullet\to Y$ and then $X\otimes_R^\mathbf{L}Y$ is represented by the complex $\operatorname{Tot}(X[0]\otimes_R K_\bullet)$, which you can see from the definition is just $X\otimes_R K_n$ in the $n$-th position. In particular we can take $P_\bullet\to Y$ to be a projective resolution of $Y$ (remember $Y$ is just an $R$-module), for which we know [classically](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0646) we can arrange for $P_n=0$ for $n<0$, then by Lemma $15.58.9$ on the link I've provided (replacing "bounded above" by "bounded below”, etc.) this is a K-flat resolution of $Y$, and then you can see our complex representing $X\otimes_R^\mathbf{L}Y$ is concentrated in degree $\ge0$, resulting in the claim $H_{-n}(X\otimes_R^\mathbf{L}Y)=0$ for $n>0$.

Similarly one can compute [RHom](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A5W) by taking a [K-injective](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/070G) resolution $Y\to I_\bullet$ and then $\mathbf{R}\mathrm{Hom}_R(X,Y)$ is represented by the complex $\operatorname{Hom}_\bullet(X[0],I_\bullet)$. Lemma $13.31.4$ in the second link says one can take $Y\to I_\bullet$ to be an injective resolution of the $R$-module $Y$, for which one knows we can always arrange for $I_n=0$ for $n>0$, and then you can see again that our complex representing $\mathbf{R}\mathrm{Hom}_R(X,Y)$ is concentrated in degree $\le0$.

Comment: The question wasn't about whether ext=tor, it was about whether they were both equal to 0 in a certain range, which (assuming indexing) would follow from the existence of a projective resolution concentrated in non-negative degrees quasi-isomorphic to the given complexes.  However, I am not immediately sure of this fact.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your proof is right ... the philosophy as I had in mind is that since $X,Y$ are basically modules, so they should not have any negative Tor neither any negative Ext ...

Comment: +1 Yes. This proof is completely correct. A minor comment is that one doesn't need to talk about $K$-flat/injective resolutions in this case. Since these complexes live in $D^b(R)=D^+(R)\cap D^-(R)$ one can define these functors 'just' on the usual injective and projective resolutions .
Even then the proof largely follows the skeleton above.